# SVG image as background displays totally different on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have this SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100">
 <polygon points="8,0 8,7 14,12 14,94 92,94 97,91 97,15 99,13 99,0" id="p2" style="fill:none; stroke-width: 1px;" stroke="#555555"/>
</svg>
```

which I am using as a background for a div like this:

```
background:url("images/global/lineas.svg") no-repeat 0 0 / 100% 100%;
width:280px;
height:130;
```

On Firefox the image extends in width and height to cover the div container, on Chrome the result is totally different because the height won't fit, only the width.

I want what Firefox does. The image should stretch and fit the container accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome seems to be preserving the aspect ratio of the image. You can disable that though.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <polygon points="8,0 8,7 14,12 14,94 92,94 97,91 97,15 99,13 99,0" id="p2" style="fill:none; stroke-width: 1px;" stroke="#555555"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. I cant believe the answer was so simple and I couldnt figure it out myself. But why is viewbox necessary?

Comment: From [the SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute). If attribute ‘viewBox’ is not provided, then ‘preserveAspectRatio’ is ignored.

Comment: Really? But I omitted it now and nevertheless preserveAspectRatio is not being ignored on any browser.

Comment: There are strange unwritten rules regarding images. It's easier to be explicit in what you want than omit things and rely on broswers defaulting to things.

Comment: Okay, I will keep it then.